# Broken promise getting a user

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I may be making a Promise faux pas but after authenticating a user I want to load the user's profile into the `App.Session` singleton that I've created:

```
App.Session.set(
    'userProfile', 
    self.get('store').find('user',App.Session.get('userId'))
);
```

This results in the API call being made and a valid resultset being returned but for some reason in the debugger I get an empty result. Specifically, I do see the `User.id` but the rest of the columns are blank.

From the debugger, here's the JSON response:

```
{
  "user": {
    "id": "1",
    "username": "jsmith",
    "name": {
      "first_name": "Joe",
      "last_name": "Smith"
    },
    "emails": [
      {
        "id": "52153c0330063",
        "name": "work-1",
        "type": "other",
        "address": "new@notreally.com",
        "comments": "",
        "status": "active",
        "is_primary": false
      },
      {
        "id": "52153d1b90ad0",
        "name": "work-2",
        "type": "other",
        "address": "old@yesreally.com",
        "comments": "",
        "status": "active",
        "is_primary": true
      },
  ]
}
```

I'm a little new to Promises and so I thought maybe if I changed the code to:

```
self.get('store').find('user',App.Session.get('userId')).then( function(profile){
    App.Session.set('userProfile', profile);
});
```

I felt pretty good about my new Promise acumen as I wrote this new code. Sadly my proud moment was greeted with failure. My second code snippet behaves precisely the same as the first one. Huh?

Can anyone help?

--------- ** UPDATE ** ---------

I've now including the model definition for `User` and a picture of the debugger window I made reference to.

### User Model

```
App.RawTransform = DS.Transform.extend({
    deserialize: function(serialized) {
        return serialized;
    },  
    serialize: function(deserialized) {
        return deserialized;
    }
});
App.NameTransform = DS.Transform.extend({
    deserialize: function(serialized) {
        return App.Name.create(serialized);
    },
    serialize: function(deserialized) {
        return JSON.stringify(deserialized);
    }
});

App.User = DS.Model.extend({
    username: DS.attr("string"),
    name: DS.attr("name"),
    roles: DS.attr("raw"),
    goals: DS.attr("raw"),
    places: DS.attr("raw"),
    emails: DS.attr("raw"),
    networks: DS.attr("raw"),
    relationships: DS.attr("raw"),
    services: DS.attr("raw"),
    uom: DS.attr("raw"),
});
```

### Debug Window

Prior to login the model viewer looks like this:
[image: before]

Then after login it looks like this:

[image: after]

And then looking at the record details we see:

[image: details]

Comment: Your code looks good.  How are you seeing that those fields are empty?  What do your models look like?

Comment: @Daniel I've added more details to the question to address your question. Btw, when you say the code looks ok, were you referring to my code at the top (first attempt) or my later attempt to more Promise literate?

Comment: For what it's worth I did notice a difference between the two methods ... in the second method I get some errors in the debugger that I still haven't sorted out and there is NOT a `User` record added.

Comment: I was referring to the promise, that's the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the answer seems to be down to two things. First of all, the second code snippet for handling the promise that I tried:

```
self.get('store').find('user',App.Session.get('userId')).then( function(profile){
    App.Session.set('userProfile', profile);
});
```

is the **correct** way to go. The first method just leaves you with a "broken promise" in a "broken heart" sort of way not technically speaking but the point is it doesn't work.

The reason that my second promise implementation didn't work though was down to the `Model` indirectly and very specifically down to the deserializer I had put in place for `Names`.

I was scratching my head on this for second as the deserializer had worked back in the Ember-Data v0.1x world so I did what seemed appropriate ... I blamed Ember-Data. Come on, we've all done it. The fact is that Ember-Data had nothing to do with it and once I was willing to accept the blame I realised that it was simply a matter of not having moved my `Name` object over to the project I'm currently working on. Doh!